# Setting HTML "title" attribute with JS doesn't render &amp;

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, title

What is the proper way to use an ampersand in the title attribute? I would have assumed that you should use `&amp;`, but it gives different behavior depending on whether it was set in the original HTML or modified with JS.

Tooltip rendering in Chrome (Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)) and Safari (Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9)):

[image]
[image: with JS]

https://jsfiddle.net/davegaeddert/femm9b96/

Comment: &amp; is a HTML (well XML actually) entity, so should only be used in literal HTML

Comment: @SimonPlus Not necessarily: `node.innerHTML = 'you &amp; me'`

Comment: @JuanMendes Well I guess you could argue that string get's parsed as html, so it's still literal HTML

Comment: @SinonPlus Then why isn't an attribute value also considered HTML?

Comment: @JuanMendes It is, up until it gets parsed to DOM. innerHTML isn't in the DOM standard, it's just something they added to support "dynamic" parsing.

Comment: @SimonPlus `innerHTML` may have been added later, but it is in the standard https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-innerHTML

Comment: @JuanMendes This is the DOM standard: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&amp;` means `&` **in HTML**.

`&amp;` means `&amp;` when you are directly manipulating the DOM using a DOM API.

If you aren't writing HTML, don't use HTML entities.

Comment: Isn't a node attribute also HTML?

Comment: @JuanMendes No, when setting an attribute with JS, you're actually setting it on the DOM. DOM =/= HTML

Comment: @SimonPlus Actually, when you set an attribute is sets both the HTML and the DOM properties. Just check the node's `innerHTML`

Comment: @JuanMendes — No. HTML includes syntax for creating attributes. In the DOM it is DOM, not HTML. When you read `innerHTML` it explicitly serializes the DOM to HTML)

Comment: @JuanMendes No. The value of innerHTML gets constructed when you ask for it, based on the DOM tree, I think

Comment: @SimonPlus I meant something else. I mean that if I do `node.value="something"`, then `node.innerHTML` does not contain the new value, so that doesn't affect the HTML. However, if you do `node.setAttribute('value', 'something')` then `node.innerHTML` does include the new value (as does `node.value`).

Comment: @JuanMendes — Some JS properties are defined as mapping directly onto attribute values (which will then be represented if you serialise the element to HTML), some are not. Either way, the property will still be DOM and not HTML (unless it is explicitly set up to be otherwise, and I can't think of any examples other than `innerHTML` and `outerHTML`)

Answer (score 0):

The method is different depending on how you set it. In raw HTML, you have to escape the ampersand, and your fiddle is doing it correctly:

```
title="&amp;"
```

In JavaScript, you can just use `"&"` in a string:

```
jQuery("#with-js").attr("title","&");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because setAttribute does not parse attributes as HTML. See the specification for [Node.setAttribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082)

When directly in the HTML, it will be parsed for HTML entities

**Excerpt**

> This value is a simple string; it is not parsed as it is being set. So any markup (such as syntax to be recognized as an entity reference) is treated as literal text

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082